# MySQL query randomly slow

Tags: mysql, vbulletin

I have a query running in vBulletin system, that fetches latest threads that have image attachments, along with their first attachment ID.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  thread.threadid, 
          thread.title, 
          thread.postuserid, 
          thread.postusername,
          thread.dateline, 
          thread.replycount, 
          post.pagetext,
          (
            SELECT attachment.attachmentid
            FROM `vb_attachment` AS attachment
                LEFT JOIN `vb_filedata` AS data 
                    ON data.filedataid=attachment.filedataid
            WHERE attachment.contentid=thread.firstpostid
                AND attachment.contenttypeid=1
                AND data.extension IN('jpg','gif','png')
                AND data.thumbnail_filesize>0
            ORDER BY attachmentid ASC
            LIMIT 1
          ) AS firstattachmentid
FROM `vb_thread` AS thread
   LEFT JOIN `vb_post` AS post 
        ON post.postid=thread.firstpostid
WHERE thread.forumid IN(331, 318)
        HAVING firstattachmentid>0
ORDER BY thread.dateline DESC
LIMIT 0, 5
```

The explain results for the query you can see here:

[image]

The problem: usually query runs in 0.00001 second, so almost instantly, as it is optimized query overall, however, after creating new thread (**even if thread is not from forums IDs 331, 318**), it takes 40+ seconds (executed directly from MySQL GUI), and **even explain query takes 2+ seconds!**. Explain query taking slow shows the same results regarding index usage.

After running the same query two-three times, it is back to usual speed.

If anyone could explain what happens, and how to fix the problem, I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL caches the results of queries to allow it to return the results of the same query quicker later.

Adding a new thread is causing MySQL to have to rebuild the query cache the next time the query is run.

I have found MySQL subqueries to perform badly. Some tactics I have used to avoid subqueries:

1. Restructure the query as a join without subqueries.
2. Restructure the query as several queries.
3. Return more data that you need and then do some work with this data in your application.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. It seems query cache is the only thing that can explain this for now. However, I am still unsure as "explain" shows that exactly one row is used by sub-queries, and only 100 rows in the main query, shouldn't this run faster (at least no 45 seconds) even without query cache?

Comment: I am accepting your answer as there are no other answers so far. Anyway, this seems to be largely connected with MySQL table engine, e, server version etc. so everyone having such issue should try to change these and see what happens.

Comment: I have found MySQL subqueries to behave much slower than I think they should. I don't know why. I avoid them.